# c# MongoDB query builder for each loop

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'am trying to query a document of the specified objectID from a collection and get the nested array from that document.

Here is the sample of a document from my collection.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f46d20793f2c2dd4eaaa60"),
    "academicQualifications" : [ 
        {
            "degreeCompleted" : "Masters' in other fields",
            "degree" : "Master in Engineering Education",
            "when" : "2010-present",
            "Where" : "WIT, Iloilo CIty",
            "Remarks" : "12 units earned, Ongoing"
        }, 
        {
            "degreeCompleted" : "Masters' in other fields",
            "degree" : "MS Computer Engineering",
            "when" : "1995-200",
            "Where" : "WIT",
            "Remarks" : ""
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my entity

```
 class facultyData 
    {  
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public List<acadQualifications> academicQualifications { get; set; }  
    }
class acadQualifications
    {
        public ObjectId _id { get; set; }
        public string degreeCompleted { get; set; }
        public string degree { get; set; }
        public string when { get; set; }
        public string where { get; set; }
        public string remarks { get; set; }
    }
```

So what I wanted to accomplish is, to get the "degree", "when", "where" and remarks values from each item of the array and append them to a string that I will later be used for a table.

Here's what it should look like on a string.

For the degree,
"Master in Engineering Education / MS Computer Engineering"
the same with when, where, remarks.

Comment: Try printing `academicQualifications[x].degreeCompleted` It might give you what you want.

Comment: From your question it is rather unclear what you are trying to accomplish, can you please give a clear example of the output string?

Comment: @chridam Let's say we have the string for the degree keys, the output should be "Master in Engineering Education / MS Computer Engineering". Each value will append to the string.

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/a/20662135/897882

Comment: @krikara Thanks, I'm trying the solution you gave at this moment. I'm going to post the answer later. +1